# Resources for building a simple image search using TensorFlow

Tags: computer-vision, tensorflow, image-recognition

I need to implement a simple image search in my app using TensorFlow.
The requirements are these:

1. The dataset contains around a million images, all of the same size, each containing one unique object and **only** that object.
2. The search parameter is an image taken with a phone camera of some object that is potentially in the dataset.

I've managed to extract the image from the camera picture and straighten it to rectangular form and as a result, a reverse-search image indexer like TinEye was able to find a match.

Now I want to reproduce that indexer by using TensorFlow to create a model based on my data-set (make each image's file name a unique index).

Could anyone point me to tutorials/code that would explain how to achieve such thing without diving too much into computer vision terminology?

Comment: Why using TensorFlow? While deep learning is a great tool for many computer vision problems, it is probably not the right solution for image search.

Comment: I'm open to suggestions :)

Comment: The standard approach is: extract local features (SIFT or SIFT like) -> compute visual words -> search images with similar visual words (similar to document search). optionally verify match using homography (or other geometric model). You can look online for bag-of-words image search

Comment: AI for getting a feature vector, [vector database ("new technology")](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=klTvEwg3oJ4) to find closest matches. all in one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mBcBoGhFndY

Answer (score 10):

The [Wikipedia article on TinEye](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TinEye) says that [Perceptual Hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptual_hashing) will yield results similar to TinEye's. They reference [this detailed description of the algorithm](http://www.hackerfactor.com/blog/index.php?/archives/432-Looks-Like-It.html). But [TinEye refuses to comment.](http://blog.tineye.com/tineye-is-magic/)

---

The biggest issue with the Perceptual Hashing approach is that while it's efficient for identifying the same image (subject to skews, contrast changes, etc.), it's not great at identifying a completely different image of the same object (e.g. the front of a car vs. the side of a car).

TensorFlow has great support for deep neural nets which might give you better results. Here's a high level description of how you might use a deep neural net in TensorFlow to solve this problem:

Start with a pre-trained NN (such as GoogLeNet) or train one yourself on a dataset like [ImageNet](http://www.image-net.org/). Now we're given a new picture we're trying to identify. Feed that into the NN. Look at the activations of a fairly deep layer in the NN. This vector of activations is like a 'fingerprint' for the image. Find the picture in your database with the closest fingerprint. If it's sufficiently close, it's probably the same object.

The intuition behind this approach is that unlike Perceptual Hashing, the NN is building up a high-level representation of the image including identifying edges, shapes, and important colors. For example, the fingerprint of an apple might include information about its circular shape, red color, and even its small stem.

---

You could also try something like [this 2012 paper on image retrieval](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00530-012-0265-1) which uses a slew of hand-picked features such as SIFT, regional color moments and object contour fragments. This is probably a lot more work and it's not what TensorFlow is best at.

---

**UPDATE**

OP has provided an example pair of images from his application:

[image: Image in the database]
[image: Image from the user. Should match something in the database.]

Here are the results of using [the demo on the pHash.org website](http://www.phash.org/demo/) on that pair of similar images as well as on a pair of completely dissimilar images.

**Comparing the two images provided by the OP:**

RADISH (radial hash): `pHash determined your images are not similar with PCC = 0.518013`

DCT hash: `pHash determined your images are not similar with hamming distance = 32.000000.`

Marr/Mexican hat wavelet: `pHash determined your images are not similar with normalized hamming distance = 0.480903.`

**Comparing one of his images with a random image from my machine:**

RADISH (radial hash): `pHash determined your images are not similar with PCC = 0.690619.`

DCT hash: `pHash determined your images are not similar with hamming distance = 27.000000.`

Marr/Mexican hat wavelet: `pHash determined your images are not similar with normalized hamming distance = 0.519097.`

**Conclusion**

We'll have to test more images to really know. But so far pHash does not seem to be doing very well. With the default thresholds it doesn't consider the similar images to be similar. And for one algorithm, it actually considers a completely random image to be more similar.

Comment: I wonder what Perceptual Hash are they using, because I tried the pHash open source project and it gave atrocious results...

Comment: Can you share a link, code, or more details on what you built and what results you got?

Comment: Here: http://imgur.com/a/be89U first image is the one in database, the second is the one I am looking for

Comment: Thanks! And what results do you get from running PHash on those two images?